# Flutter google authorization response type OAuth 2

Tags: firebase, flutter, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-signin

I'm currently using google login package along with firebase auth for authorization.
I have a back-end i need to authorize my access to, when trying to verify the id token i get from google login against https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=
I get a this response:

```html
I/flutter (13234): IS OAUTH ID TOKEN VALID?: {
I/flutter (13234):   "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
I/flutter (13234):   "azp": "88741vq268aj3t4p68l.apps.googleusercontent.com",
I/flutter (13234):   "aud": "88741690snaqa206bnut93.apps.googleusercontent.com",
I/flutter (13234):   "sub": "117293359314859019528",
I/flutter (13234):   "email": "",
I/flutter (13234):   "email_verified": "true",
I/flutter (13234):   "name": "",
I/flutter (13234):   "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/",
I/flutter (13234):   "given_name": "",
I/flutter (13234):   "family_name": "",
I/flutter (13234):   "locale": "en",
I/flutter (13234):   "iat": "15826",
I/flutter (13234):   "exp": "15869426",
I/flutter (13234):   "alg": "R56",
I/flutter (13234):   "kid": "6fcf4a30ff5a",
I/flutter (13234):   "typ": "JWT"
I/flutter (13234): }
```

the problem is that it has no at_hash and jti values so it's failing verification.

Here's how i get the token,

```html
googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

String idToken = googleSignInAuthentication.idToken;

 var response = await client.get(
      'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken}'
    );

    print('${responseee.body}');
```

I know i'm supposed to pass a response type 'code' in the sign in, but i can't seem to pass it anywhere..

Help will be greatly appreciated!